# Center the div and div overflow

Tags: html, css, centering

I've just got back into web design as a hobby and have run into a few problems..
I'm trying to center a div that contains more divs which I also want centered and I'm trying to make it so the when the page is re-sized; a, the divs are still centered and b, the overflow of the divs is also centered.

[I realise this may not make to much sense so here is a link to the page](http://www.hyperhome.tk/homepage)

(if you re-size it you'll notice that the radio boxes move around and aren't centered)

[And here is a link to the page on jsfiddle (although the js isn't important)](http://jsfiddle.net/ABirchall/ngDpE/)

```
...
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code here. As soon as the problem is solved, the question has no reference points...

Comment: that's the problem, I'm not entirely sure what is relevant as I'm not sure how you would even start to go about it. I've googled it and have only found answers that center the divs when the windows has not been re-sized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have `display: inline-block` and `float: left` on `.Cbox`. Remove the `float: left`